# Weird submit button behaviour HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I made a mobile web app which contains a basic form with a submit button. My problem is that the submit button will not work on mobile devices (mobile safari). When the button is clicked nothing happens. However, it works fine on computer in all browsers. Below is the form which contains the submit button. Any ideas why this would be happening.

Form Code:

```
<form method="get" name="myForm">
    <ul class="roundbox">
        <li><input type="text" placeholder="To:" class="addr" name="addr" id="addr" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" /></li>
        <li>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="30" style="overflow::hidden" placeholder="Message" name="body" id="body" size="220" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"> </textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
            <input type="reset" class="reset" value="Clear"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="O" type="text" name="dir" id="dir" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: `<input class="reset">` should use `<input type="reset">` and remove the `[onclick]` attribute.

Comment: I have some CSS for the reset button for class="reset" so that's why it is coded the way it is. However that button is working fine, it is just the submit button that has some problem.

Comment: that's beside the point, you're using a poor choice of markup. I'm simply commenting that it could be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was with JQTouch. You need to add

```
    formSelector: false,
    useFastTouch: false,
```

to your $.jQTouch object and add class="form" to your form. Here is a conversation about this problem http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=125

Answer (score 0):

You've got some `onclick` handlers on your buttons that are unnecessary, and would be interfering with the default behavior of the buttons.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because it works fine on the computer. It only has a problem on mobile devices.

Comment: @ewein, have you tried removing them to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I just tried and same problem.

Comment: @ewein, is there any other relevant JavaScript that could be interfering with the default behavior of the buttons?

Comment: No not really, but that shouldn't matter because it works fine if I slide the screen down and push the same button when it is half off screen.

Comment: @ewein, please make a reduced test case on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It helps to see the code working in a live environment to be certain that there isn't something that you've overlooked.

Comment: A fiddle won't help since it works fine on computer which means the javascript is working as well. The problem is only when it is on mobile device. Again the button works fine when it is moved down.

Comment: If the problem is only on mobile, and we don't have a version of the code to test on mobile, there's not a lot we can do to help. Especially if the problem is with some other javascript that you aren't showing us

Comment: @ewein, a fiddle will help because I can open it on a mobile device in addition to a computer, but if you're unwilling to help yourself I'll simply vote to close this question as "not a real question" because there isn't enough information to answer it.

Comment: @ewein, also, a difference such as jQuery UI vs jQuery Mobile would make a mobile site behave differently on a hashchange, which is what's happening when you click the submit button.

Comment: I have been playing around with it and I noticed a few things. As soon as the page loads, if I do not click in the textarea it will work. If I click in the text area, this causes the keyboard to popup which in turn causes the page to move up. This is when it does not work. If I only enter information in the addr text field and not the textarea it will work. So the problem is something to do with the textarea moving the elements such that the click event is not being noticed.

Comment: @ewein, are you submitting the form without clicking the submit button? The event handler is catching the click event, which is not triggered if the form is submitted in a different manner.

Comment: @ewein, see, that's the sort of thing that's literally impossible to find out given the information provided in your question, which is why i'm going to flag this question for closure, as it will not help anyone.